# Batch File Process all files in a directory except files of type

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a section of script that currently runs through a directory of files 'processing' all files specified before deleting them:

```
for %%x in (*.J_E, *.J_T, *.J_I, *.bcc) do (
"%%x"=="*.exe" (
  set /a count=count+1
  set choice[!count!]=%%x
)
echo.
::convert files
md %FreshDate%\%FreshTime%
for /l %%x in (1,1,!count!) do (
   echo %%x. !choice[%%x]!
      tlv2txt !choice[%%x]! > %FreshDate%\%FreshTime%\!choice[%%x]!.txt
   del !choice[%%x]!
)
```

The list of files that need this processing is growing almost weekly and I think it will probably just be easier to process all files except a small number (.dll, *.exe and *.bat)

I have tried substituting this line at the start of the example above:

```
for %%x in (*.J_E, *.J_T, *.J_I, *.bcc) do (
```

with this:

```
for %%x in (*) do if not "%%x=="*.dll" if not "%%x"=="*.bat" if not "%%x"=="*.exe" (
```

but all I can manage to do with this is delete everything in the directory - including the batch file running the script!

Can anyone help?
Many Thanks

Comment: You missed the `if` command in this line: `"%%x"=="*.exe" (`! Anyway: **1.** the `for` command will _not_ return a file with an extension different than the provided list. **2.** an `if not "%%x"=="*.exe" (` command have no sense because you can not use wild-cards in a string comparison! Just eliminate such a line and directly process the files...

Answer (score 2):

your `if` construct won't work. Batch's `if` is very basic.
Use another method: `echo` the extension of your file and use `findstr` to check if the string is not (`/v`) one of the given ones.

```
for %%A in (*) do (
  echo %%~xA|findstr /v /x ".dll .bat .exe" && (
    tlv2txt %%A > %FreshDate%\%FreshTime%\%%~nA.txt
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "exclude=.dll.exe.bat."

for %%x in (*) do if "!exclude:%%~Xx.=!" equ "%exclude%" (
   echo %%x
   tlv2txt %%x > %FreshDate%\%FreshTime%\%%~Nx.txt
   del %%x
)
```

In this method the extension of the files is compared vs. a list of excluded extensions in a very simple way: the extension is removed from the list, so if the result is the same, such extension is *not* in the list. This method don't use any external command, like `find` or `findstr`, so it run faster.

Answer (score 0):

Wether inclusion nor exclusion need to be that complicated:

```
:: Inclusion
For /f "Delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B *.J_E *.J_T *.J_I *.bcc'
) Do tlv2txt "%%A" > "%FreshDate%\%FreshTime%\%%~nA.txt"

:: Exclusion
For /f "Delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B  ^| findstr /i /V ".bat$ .cmd$ .exe$ .dll$" '
) Do tlv2txt "%%A" > "%FreshDate%\%FreshTime%\%%~nA.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also remove the unnecessary for loop and just have one:

```bat
If Not Exist "%FreshDate%%FreshTime%\" MD "%FreshDate%%FreshTime%"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/B/A-D^|FindStr/VIE "\.dll \.exe \.bat') Do (
    tlv2txt "%%A">"%FreshDate%%FreshTime%\%%~nA.txt" 2>Nul
    If Not ErrorLevel 1 Del "%%A"))
```

Please not that I was unable to determine the format of your `%FreshTime%` variable as it was excluded from your code snippet. Please make sure that it doesn't contain a trailing backspace.